# Why do we require $X$ to be a finite set when we count $|X|$ via orbits?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, orbit-stabilizer

$\newcommand{\stab}{\text{stab}}$
**Proposition:** Let $G$ be a group acting on a finite set $X$. Let $N$ be the number or orbits of $X$ under this action, and for each orbit let $x_i \in X$ be some element in the orbit. Then
$$
 |X| = \sum_{i=1}^N[G:\stab(x_i)].
 $$

The proof is a direct appication of the orbit-stabilizer theorem but why do we need to require that $|X|< \infty$ here? If $X$ was an infinite then at least one of the orbits is going to be infinite because the orbits partition $X$, but then won't this still hold? Sorry I assume I'm missing something evident. Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: There is no reason for an orbit to be infinite...the group might act trivially on the infinite set.  $N$ would then be infinite and the sum would diverge.  One could modifying the claim to cover that case, but what content would the theorem then have?

Comment: $N$ may not be finite and it might be any non-zero cardinal $\le \lvert X\rvert$, but the natural adaptation that $X$ is the disjoint union of the the orbits, and it's therefore in bijection with the disjoint union of the cardinals of the indices of the stabilizers of a selection of representatives (if such selection exists) is true. Your assessment seems simplistic, at least at a terminological level, but if you're acquainted with infinite cardinals you'll figure out to what extent it's true when $N<\aleph_0$.

Comment: Oh I hadn't realized that at all! I guess I'm not as comfortable with actions as I thought.Thanks very much @lulu!

Comment: Speaking only of infinite vs. finite (without talking about cardinality), the natural extension of this proposition seems to be "if $X$ is infinite, then either there are infinitely many orbits or at least one orbit's stabilizer has infinite index in $G$".